# Getting HTML table column name based on column (td) in XPath

Tags: html, xslt, xpath

I'm stepping through each row's column (td) in a table, and trying to get the associated column name, but having some trouble. I'm hoping to do this programmatically as I don't always know the number of columns in the table, and I have to repeat this many times throughout the project.

Edit: this needs to be XSLT 1.0 due to tool requirements.

Example XML/HTML:

```
<text>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Allergy Name</th>
                <th>Reaction Description</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Severity</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Provider</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>MUCINEX D</td>
                <td>Hallucinations</td>
                <td>2015/11/19</td>
                <td>Critical</td>
                <td>Active</td>
                <td>Mickey Mouse, MD</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</text>
```

XSLT snippet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tr">
<!-Getting other data here-->
   <xsl:for-each select="td">
            <xsl:value-of select="~COLUMN NAME~"/> <!--Looking for the column name here-->
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Ideally I'd get something like:

```
Allergy Name: MUCINEX D
```

and so on through each column in the table.

Comment: Have you tried `<xsl:value-of select="text()" />`?

Comment: I don't think that will work. Are you thinking using select="text()" while on the Table context? That won't get the header name and the value on the same row. I cannot use the table text as is, and need to pivot it a bit in order to use it.

Comment: Apologies - it wasn't obvious to me that you wanted the header value as well

Comment: What should the result be if the source table has more than one data row?

Comment: The full XSLT is only going row by row, and doing other functions on it, so it throws each one into it's own node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following XSLT-1.0 code. Of course you have to adjust some of the paths to your actual file layout.

```
<xsl:for-each select="table/tbody/tr">
    <!-- Getting other data here-->
    <xsl:for-each select="td">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="../../../thead/tr/th[$pos]"/> <!--Looking for the column name here-->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(': ',.)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The variable saves the current position in the set of `td` elements and uses it as index into the `th` elements. The `th` elements are accessed by a relative path; an absolute path may be better, but that depends on the file layout and if you're dealing with several tables or only one.

**Its output is:**

```
Allergy Name: MUCINEX D
Reaction Description: Hallucinations
Start Date: 2015/11/19
Severity: Critical
Status: Active
Provider: Mickey Mouse, MD
```

---

Alternatively you can use an `xsl:key` with a small trick. Possibly this is faster, but it's uncomfortable with multiple tables.

However, this is how a stylesheet could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
    <xsl:key name="hdr" match="tr/th" use="count(preceding-sibling::th) + 1" />

    <xsl:template match="/text">
        <xsl:for-each select="table/tbody/tr">
            <!-- Getting other data here-->
            <xsl:for-each select="td">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('hdr',position())" /> 
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(': ',.)"/>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is the same.

Comment: oh, I didn't even think about using a key or variable. That works!